# MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError)

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql://root:Mudit@2008@localhost/sys"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Website(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False
    assword = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
def op():
    if request.method=='POST':
         titlei = request.form.get('username')
         desci = request.form.get('passwordi')
         dodo = Website(username=titlei,password=desci)
         db.session.add(dodo)
         db.session.commit()
    return render_template('register.html')
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2059, 
     "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified 
      module could not be found.\r\n")
```

hey I am getting this error in flask program .please help  me to resolve this issue.
I will be thankful to you